# Capture /dev/tty in sub sub shell

Tags: bash, shell, tty

I have tow bash files.

File Child

```
echo some text | tee /dev/tty
```

File Parent

```
my_variable=$(./Child)
```

Executing ./Child prints "some text", executing ./Parent prints "some text" twice. So far so good.

However, if I modify Child file to:

```
a=$(echo some text | tee /dev/tty)
```

Then Child still prints "some text" but Parent only prints once, and my_variable is an empty variable.

Is there a way to capture the value from /dev/tty on the parent?

Comment: data written to /dev/tty cannot be read by other processes. what's your purpose?

Comment: I have a program that I want to write a wrapper around. The wrapper is Child. I want to keep the output of the program (mocked for the example with echo) while saving it to a variable, that's why I'm using | tee /dev/tty  as in this response https://serverfault.com/questions/989742/tee-and-assigning-to-variable. Now, I want to test my wrapper, that's why I have Parent, which mocks the program, executes the wrapper and checks the result

Comment: I was going to write this suggestion as an answer  - https://serverfault.com/a/989827, did you try that?

Comment: @Inian that makes the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim: Or just - `{ a=$(echo some text | tee /dev/tty >&3); } 3>&1`